# How to create all possible permutations including duplicates?

Tags: java, permutation

I wish to create all permutations of all digits from a function.

For e.g. I have the array [1,2,3].
I would like the function to first print all possible permutations of 1 digit numbers:

```
1
2
3
```

then all possible permutations of 2-digit numbers(duplicates like 11, 22, 33 included)

```
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
```

and similarly for the 3 digit numbers.

I want to include all sort of possible permutations(11, 111, 222 etc.) up to the number of digits in the array, like in this example, I would like to have all permutations up to 3 digits.
How can I write it?

My current code creates only exclusive permutations of only the number of digits asked, not the smaller digits:

```
public class Permutation {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "132546";
        int n = str.length();
        Permutation permutation = new Permutation();

        permutation.permute(str, 0, n-1);

    }

    private void permute(String str, int l, int r)
    {
        if (l == r)
            System.out.println(str);
        else
        {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            {
                str = swap(str,l,i);
                permute(str, l+1, r);
                str = swap(str,l,i);
            }
        }
    }


    public String swap(String a, int i, int j)
    {
        char temp;
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
        temp = charArray[i] ;
        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
        charArray[j] = temp;
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }

}
```

I want it to create all permutations as written above.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What doesn’t work with your existing code?

Comment: @DaveNewton Updated, could you please check now.

Comment: It looks like the heart of your difficulty is the use of the word "permutations."  A permutation is an ordering of a set. "All permutations" is therefore "all orderings." That's not the problem you're solving. Rather it's producing all N-digit numbers with a given set of digits. This is a different problem. It appears you Googled "permutations" and then tried to copy-and-paste without understanding.  As a solution technique, this a dangerous way to go.

Comment: You can solve this problem in a similar manner, by generating the distinct subsets of order 1, then order 2, and so on up to order n. Then it's just generating the permutations of those subsets. Order 1 is the easiest, just print the array. Order `n` is also just the whole array fed through permutations.

Comment: @Gene Appreciate the clarity you've tried to put in. To be precise, I'm solving for a full Cartesian Set or direct product. I meant all possible permutations for all sets of digits (1 through n).

Comment: Sorry. You're still not using the right word, and using the wrong one is leading you astray. These aren't permutations. They're properly called "combinations with replacement."  You're looking for all combinations of size K drawn from digits 1..N.  K is the number of digits desired in the output.

Comment: @Gene "Combinations with replacement" for a set {A,B,C,D,E} would yield 5+15+35+70+126 = 251 combinations. 
In my case, it would yield, (for a given n, n^n+n^n-1+n^n-2+..+n^1) 5^5+5^4+5^3+5^2+5^1= 3905 combinations. Would you still call it what you're calling it?

Comment: @Gene It's not `all N-digit numbers with a given set of digits`, rather it is: summation of all n, n-1, n-2,.. & n-n+1 digit numbers, for a given n.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Permutation {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "123456";
    
        Permutation permutation = new Permutation();

        permutation.printAll(str);
    
    }

    private void printAll(String str) {
        int n = str.length();
        for(int k=1;k<=n;k++) {//k - number of digits
            System.out.println("=================");
            System.out.println(k + " digit(s):");
            printPermutationsWithRepet(str,k);
        }
    }

    private void printPermutationsWithRepet(String str, int k) {
        String [] a =new String [k];
        printPermutations(str,k,0,1, a);
    }
    
    private void printPermutations(String str, int k, int startPosition, int maxUsed, String [] a) {    
        if(startPosition == k) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        } else {
            for(int i = maxUsed; i <= str.length(); i++) {
                a[startPosition] = str.charAt(i-1)+"";
                printPermutations(str,k,startPosition+1,i, a);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: what's the use of 2-D array `table`?
@yuri777

Comment: @Super User It was a mistake:) I updated the code

Comment: yes, not a problem, I got it, was just confirming, thanks. @yuri777

Answer (score 1):

Note that the way the digits change is like the odometer on a car (but with funky non-standard digits). So one way to go is "simulate" the odometer. No fancy recursion needed.

```java
class Odometer {
  private final int[] digits = {1, 2, 3};
  /** Indices into the digits array. Initially all zero. */
  private final int[] indices = new int[2];

  /** Advance to the next value, returning whether it's a non-repeat. */
  boolean next() {
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
      // If incrementing the current digit index causes it to "wrap."
      if (++indices[i] == digits.length) {      
        indices[i] = 0;  // It wrapped. Reset this index and keep going.
      } else {        
        return true;  // Otherwise it didn't wrap. We're done.
      }
    }
    return false;  // All indices have wrapped back to zero.
  }

  /** Print current digits. */
  void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
      System.out.print(digits[indices[i]]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Odometer odo = new Odometer();
    do {
      odo.print();
    } while (odo.next());
  }
}
```

A more general comment is that this isn't a permutation problem. It appears your initial solution is based on that mistake. The code *is* for the all permutations problem. Consequently it's not close to correct. If that's the result of Googling for "permutations" and copy/pasting code you didn't understand, pause and take stock. This is not a useful strategy. It will end badly.